# Get unique values in array and count without array functions

Tags: php, arrays

**I have an array :**

```
$arrData = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);
```

Without using any array defualt function, i want to get the count of the array...

**Condition:**

Duplicate array values must be considered as 1 value.

Please provide your logic that could help to find my answer without array functions...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried ? What are your results ? What is bothering you ? Posting one's assignment on StackOverflow hoping that someone will do them for you is not well considered, you have to at least try something.

Comment: We don't do homework.

Comment: Actually it was a question asked in an interview.. and i even have no idea.. i tried to search but everybody is using the functions.. so i add this question here...

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get count of array without duplicates you can do it this way:

```
<?php

$arrData = array(3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9);
$out = array();

foreach ($arrData as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item, $out)) {
        $out[] = $item;
    }
}


echo count ($out);
```

And if you want to know number of occurences you can do it this way:

```
<?php

$arrData = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);

$out = array();

foreach ($arrData as $item) {
    if (isset($out[$item])) {
        ++$out[$item];
    }
    else {
        $out[$item] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($out as $item => $count) {
    echo $item.' '.$count."<br />";
}

echo count($out);
```

You simple iterate over each element using loop and create new array with keys that are values from first array and values that are number of occurrences.

Comment: Buddy i need total count at the end.. the duplicate will be considered as 1 value.. so the count i want in result will be : 8

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<?php
    $arrData    = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);
    $tmpArray   = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach($arrData as $k => $v)
    {
        if(!in_array($v, $tmpArray))
        {
            $tmpArray[$k] = $v; 
            $i++;
        }
    }

    echo "Unique array size is: ".$i;
?>
```

Without `in_array`

```
<?php
    $arrData    = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);
    $tmpArray   = array();

    foreach($arrData as $k => $v)
    {
        $tmpArray[$k] = $v; 
    }

    $i = 0;
    foreach($tmpArray as $k => $v)
    {
        $i++;
    }

    echo "Unique array size is: ".$i;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks thats really working .. but if we don't have to use in_array function? can we still get the same result @S.Pols

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, then you would get somethink like this. (see above)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arrData = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);

foreach($arrData as $x){
  foreach($arrData as $y=>$t){
      if($x == $y){
          $array[$x] =0;
      }else{
          $array[$x] =1;

      }
   }
}
$numCount =0;
foreach($array  as $q=>$r){
   $numCount +=1;
}
echo $numCount ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this php function

```
$arrData = array(3,5,5,8,7,6,3,1,2,8,9);
array_count_values($arrData );
 print_r($arrData );
```

widtout function default for dublicat array value

```
$arrData = array(3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9);

    $i=0;
   $valueArray='';
$newDublicatValue=array();
foreach($arrData as $key=>$value){

    if ($arrData[$key]==$valueArray){
        $newDublicatValue[]=$arrData[$key];
    }
    $valueArray=$arrData[$key];

}
print_r($newDublicatValue);
```

---

or use this function for remove dublicate value in array

```
$result = array_unique($arrData );
print_r($result);
```

widtout function default for dublicat array value

```
$arrData = array(3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9);

    $i=0;
   $valueArray='';
$newDublicatValue=array();
foreach($arrData as $key=>$value){

    if ($arrData[$key]==$valueArray){
       unset($arrData[$i]);
    }
    $valueArray=$arrData[$i];
    $i++;

}
print_r($arrData);
```

Comment: "Please provide your logic that could help to find my answer without array functions..."

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $arr1 = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,1,3,5,3,20];    
  print_r(arr_unique($arr1)); // will print unique values
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Unique value count => ".count(arr_unique($arr1)); // Will print unique value count
  echo "<br>";
  arr_count_val($arr1); // will print array with duplicate values

  function arr_unique($arr) {
      sort($arr);
      $curr = $arr[0];
      $uni_arr[] = $arr[0];
      for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++){
          if($curr != $arr[$i]) {
              $uni_arr[] = $arr[$i];
              $curr = $arr[$i];
          }
      }
      return $uni_arr;
  }

  function arr_count_val($arr) {
      $uni_array = arr_unique($arr);
      $count = 0;
      foreach($uni_array as $n1) {
          foreach($arr as $n2) {
              if($n1 == $n2) {
                  $count++;
              }
          }
          echo "$n1"." => "."$count"."<br>";
          $count=0; 
      }
  }
?>
```